# How fix paypal error with response code 400

Tags: laravel-5, paypal-sandbox

Implementing paypal in my laravel 5.8 app

I got error :

```
Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-NNNNNNNNNN/execute.
```

My control :

```
public function paypal_payment_execute()
{
    // After Step 1
    $apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
            'NNNNN',     // ClientID
            'NNNNN'      // ClientSecret
        )
    );

    $paymentId = request('paymentId');
    $PayerID = request('PayerID');

    $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);

    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId( $PayerID);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $amount = new Amount();
    $details = new Details();

    $details->setShipping(1.2)
            ->setTax(1.3)
            ->setSubtotal(17.50); //

    $amount->setCurrency('USD');
    $total_sum= 20; // I check this sum is setShipping + setTax + setSubtotal

    $amount->setTotal( (integer)$total_sum); 

    $amount->setDetails($details);
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);

    $execution->addTransaction( [ $transaction ] );  // !!! I found that here must be an array?

    try {
        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);  // Number of error points at this line
    } catch (Exception $pce) {
        echo '<pre>::'.print_r( json_decode($pce->getData()) );
        die("-1 XXZ  app/Http/Controllers/PaymentController.php");
    }
    return $result;


}
```

I my browse I see output : https://prnt.sc/od3b6v
1) Can somebody say which kind of error is it ?

2) I see lines like :

```
$this->logger->info
```

Is it some logging ? Where can I look into it ?

3) That was very strange that error line was shown and not pre output in try catch block:
I expected to see pce->getData output:

```
} catch (Exception $pce) {
    echo '<pre>::'.print_r( json_decode($pce->getData()) );
    die("-1 XXZ  app/Http/Controllers/PaymentController.php");
}
```

4) Searching I net I checked that making payment With JS code I set the same total and return urls, like :

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
   let total_sum= 20
   alert( "-123  total_sum::"+(total_sum) )
   paypal.Button.render({
      // Configure environment
      env: 'sandbox',
      client: {
         sandbox: 'NNNNN',
         production: 'demo_production_client_id'
      },
      locale: 'en_US',
      style: {
         size: 'small',
         color: 'blue',
         shape: 'pill',
      },

      commit: true,

      payment: function(data, actions) {
         var payment = actions.payment.create({

            "note_to_payer": "Contact us for any questions on your order.",

            "intent": "sale",
            "payer": {
               "payment_method": "paypal"
            },

            redirect_urls : { //redirect_urls
               return_url : '...paypal_payment',
               cancel_url : '.../paypal_payment_cancel'
            },

            transactions: [{
               amount: {
                  total:  Number( total_sum ),
                  currency: 'USD'
               }
            }]
         });
         return payment;

      },
      onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
         return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            return actions.redirect();
         });
      }
   }, '#paypal-button');

</script>
```

How fix it ?

composer.json :

```
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    ...
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
```

**Modified :**

No messages inside of PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException block anyway.
In your link I noticed that  currency code must be checked.
I created my account about 2 weeks ago : https://prnt.sc/od385x
Where can I check currency code (and maybe country ) ?
Is it in setting for any app ? I did not find where currency can be entered.
if any webhooks must be defoned? What are they for ?

I see “Upgrade to a business account” link . Can it be relative  to my problem?

```
**Modified # 2:**
```

I attach error desctiption on my sercer in laravel.log when I got 400 error :

cat laravel.log :
    [2019-07-12 07:30:33] local.ERROR: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LUUDOCA2FR59365NU097882X/execute. {"userId":6,"exception":"[object] (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException(code: 400): Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LUUDOCA2FR59365NU097882X/execute. at /var/www/html/votes/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:207)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php(78): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{\"payer_id\":\"Z9...')
    #1 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalResourceModel.php(104): PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{\"payer_id\":\"Z9...', Array)
    #2 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php(650): PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{\"payer_id\":\"Z9...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext), Object(PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall))
    #3 /var/www/html/votes/app/Http/Controllers/PaymentController.php(108): PayPal\Api\Payment->execute(Object(PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution), Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext))
    #4 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController->paypal_payment_execute()
    #5 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #6 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('paypal_payment_...', Array)
    #7 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(219): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController), 'paypal_payment_...')
    #8 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
    #9 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(680): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
    #10 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #11 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #12 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #13 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #14 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(75): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #15 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #16 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #17 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #18 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #19 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #20 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #21 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #22 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #23 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #24 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #25 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #26 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #27 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #28 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #29 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #30 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(682): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #31 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(657): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #32 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(623): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
    #33 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(612): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #34 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #35 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #36 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/src/RemoteValidationMiddleware.php(53): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #37 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Proengsoft\JsValidation\RemoteValidationMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #38 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #39 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(65): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #40 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\InjectDebugbar->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #41 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #42 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #43 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #44 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #45 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #46 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #47 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #48 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #49 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #50 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #51 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #52 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #53 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #54 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #55 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #56 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #57 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/itsgoingd/clockwork/Clockwork/Support/Laravel/ClockworkMiddleware.php(29): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #58 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Clockwork\Support\Laravel\ClockworkMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #59 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #60 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #61 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #62 /var/www/html/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #63 /var/www/html/votes/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #64 {main}
    "}

Casn something be found in this error text?
It breaks my mind why try { block does not trigger...

Comment: Can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501799/9193055) and check what error it returns.

Comment: Please look at Modified

Comment: Are you using your sandbox paypal account credentials to make the request? I dont think you can use real paypal accounts for the sandbox.

Comment: Yes, I suppose sandbox paypal account : https://prnt.sc/od6n9r  What bring you to such idea?

Comment: Please, take a look at Modified # 2